# How can I set display name of Azure Service Principal through az cli?

Tags: azure

I'm working with **Azure** using **az cli** and I'm creating service principal with `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name NAME` and other required parameters [(link to docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac), however in this method `--name` refers to **URI to use as the logic name** not **display name** which is automatically generated and the syntax is: `azure-cli-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS`. My question is: how can I customize **display name**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not the parameter `--name` cannot customize the display name? It's the thing that you are searching for. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm using this command: `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name http:/my-name --create-cert --cert cert_name --keyvault keyvault_name true`
And the output is:
 `"displayName": "azure-cli-date-and-time",
 "name": "http://my-name"`,

Comment: @jkrys Can you provide your command and the screenshot of the output? The CLI version is also needed.

Comment: The CLI version is 1.157.0

Comment: @jkrys Are you sure it's the Azure CLI command? not others? And what command do you use?

Comment: Now I think that the version of CLI could be the reason why it's not working like at your screen.

Comment: @jkrys I think you could update the CLI and then try it again. Well, if it works, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Can you share your az cli version before I accept it as an answer?

Comment: @jkrys Yeah, I use the latest version 2.0.81. You can install or update the Azure CLI follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).